# Integrating a series term by term in Euler's reflection formula

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

One way of proving Euler's reflection formula
$$\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c+1)=\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi c},\quad 0<c<1$$
is through the beta function and the book that I'm studying essentially boils down the proof to the evaluation of the integral
$$\int_0^1(x^{-c}-x^c)(1-x+x^2-x^3+\dots)\, dx$$
that is done term by term:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int_0^1(x^{-c}-x^c)x^n\, dx$$

How can I justify this term by term integration? I'm thinking along the lines of uniform convergence but I'm not able to progress.

The book says:

> The term by term integration is justified by showing that the tail of the integrated series tends to zero:
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}(x^{-c}-x^c)\, dx=0.$$

I can easily see why the above limit is zero, but don't understand to what theorem "showing the tail of the integrated series tends to zero" refers to.

Any help is appreciated.